# scala class level synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency

I have to address thread safety issue in the following context in an multithreaded server. API endpoints are in `APIClass`, which has a instance of `Handler`. I want `Handler` class to be thread safe so that none the methods of `Handler` has dirty read from DB. I have a approach in mind (to make `db` (instance of DB) `volatile`) but it seems to be an overkill and performance will have serious hit.

Class Hierarchy:

```
class DB {
  // Fetch  calls
  // Update calls
  // Delete calls 
}

class Handler {
  private[this] val db = new DB

  def doSomething1(...) {
    // some Fetch Calls of DB
    // some computation base upon fetched values from DB
    // some Update Calls to DB based upon above computation
  }

  def doSomething2(...) {
    // some Fetch Calls of DB
    // some computation base upon fetched values from DB
    // some Update Calls to DB based upon above computation
    // some Delete Calls
  }
}

class APIClass {
  private[this] handler = new Handler

  def API_whichCallsSomething1 {
    handler.doSomething1(...)
  }

  def API_whichCallsSomething2 {
    handler.doSomething2(...)
  }
}
```

What is the best approach to address this scenario?

PS. If someone has better title for the problem statement please feel free to update.

Comment: What you are trying to do can have serious scalability issues. Have you considered options like "optimistic locking" before deciding on this approach?

Comment: this has nothing to do with thread-safety as your concurrency is actually handled or not by the db engine